# Capture text typed from another application

Tags: c#, winapi

I am developing a window application to read text which is typed on any application on screen by `C#`.
Which I used is `Win32 API` like following - a solution I found on Google:

```
private const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
private const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

public Terminal() 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    IntPtr pFoundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();

    IntPtr notepad = FindWindow("notepad", null);
    IntPtr editx = FindWindowEx(notepad, IntPtr.Zero, "edit", null);
    int length = SendMessage(editx, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(length);
    int hr = SendMessage(editx, WM_GETTEXT, length, text);
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

But this only read existed text from Notepad. 
How should I do to read text when typing on any programs, any windows?

Comment: You need a global keyboard hook for that. (Use that phrase + *Windows* as a Google search expression.)

Comment: The way to do it is [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @KenWhite: I had found some interested things from your suggestion, thank you very much ^^

Comment: @theB: Raw Input is quite difficult, I am the new bie, thank you :)

Comment: @theB: No, definitely not. Raw Input allows you to monitor, well, raw input. It cannot know, what any given application does with that input. So when you see the sequence *[Ctrl] + A*, will that show up as *"^A"* in a text editor, or select all text, or do something else altogether, or nothing at all? The real solution here is [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable - I assumed from the question that the OP was looking for all keyboard input to arbitrary windows, not the final result of that typing.  Certainly your suggestion is the only way to go if the desired result is to get the text or end result of input.  With UI Automation do you have to poll for changes, or do you register events/callbacks?

Comment: @theB: UI Automation raises [Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671221.aspx), that clients can subscribe to (see [Subscribing to UI Automation Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671220.aspx)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following codes in your sample

```
IntPtr notepad = FindWindow("notepad", null);
```

It means to get the handle of a process which's name is `notepad`.

And the following one

```
IntPtr editx = FindWindowEx(notepad, IntPtr.Zero, "edit", null);
```

Also means you try to find a window handle from notepad, and window title is `edit`. The `edit` window is the editable area of notepad.

If you are going to make your application suitable for any process, you can not declare your target is source code. In other word, you need another way to specify a window you want to get text.

My suggestion is: You need the following Windows APIs to get target window in run-time.

For example, you can use `SetWindowsHookEx` to get a mouse event outside your application, and then it will trigger a callback when user click to a target window. Next, the callback function is triggered, you can use `GetCursorPos` to get the mouse position, and use `WindowFromPoint` to get the window which you want to read its text.

**UPDATE**

I provide my sample code from my other project, and pick up some useful part for you.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A hook handle for grabbing mouse click, used to get the position of target window.
    /// </summary>
    private IntPtr _hook = IntPtr.Zero;

    //button click event
    private void selectWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_hook != IntPtr.Zero)
            return;
        using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        {
            using (ProcessModule m = p.MainModule)
            {
                _hook = SafeNativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(SafeNativeMethods.WH_MOUSE_LL, hookCallback, SafeNativeMethods.GetModuleHandle(m.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback method of mouse hook.
    /// </summary>
    private IntPtr hookCallback(int code, IntPtr w, IntPtr l)
    {
        if (code >= 0 && (WMessages)w == WMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            CPoint pt;
            SafeNativeMethods.GetCursorPos(out pt);
            //hey man! the _windowHandle is what you need
            _windowHandle = SafeNativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(pt);
            SafeNativeMethods.UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
            _hook = IntPtr.Zero;
            //...and do your stuff here!
        }
        return SafeNativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(_hook, code, w, l);
    }
```

And the def. of Windows APIs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Window Hook ID 14 - Low level mouse proc.
    /// </summary>
    internal const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the window handle from a specified point.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="point">Specified point</param>
    /// <returns>Window handle</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(CPoint point);

    /// <summary>
    /// Register a hook.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="idHook">Hook type</param>
    /// <param name="lpfn">Function pointer</param>
    /// <param name="hMod">Module ID</param>
    /// <param name="dwThreadId">Thread ID</param>
    /// <returns>Hook handle</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    /// <summary>
    /// Unregister a hook.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hhk">Hook handle</param>
    /// <returns>Successful</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    /// <summary>
    /// Call next hook (if needed).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hhk">Hook handle</param>
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    /// <summary>
    /// Get moudle handle by module name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lpModuleName">Module name</param>
    /// <returns>Module handle</returns>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    /// <summary>
    /// Get current cursor position.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lpPoint">Output position</param>
    /// <returns>Successful</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(out CPoint lpPoint);
```

**UPDATE 2**

I forgot the CPoint struct  lol.

```
/// <summary>
/// Win32 POINT structure.
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct CPoint
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, bro! You saved my day ^^

Comment: @MrNeo
I'm on holiday and the source code are not accessible right now, but I can give you the references. `WMessage` is the enumeration of Windows Message, you can get them all from https://gist.github.com/amgine/2395987. And then, the `_windowHandle` is a `IntPtr` used to store your target window.

Comment: ah, I found ^^. Thank you very much! Have a great holiday, bro :)